# website div won't stretch from left to right, how do you fix css?

Tags: html, css, xampp

[image]

[image]

```
#header {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0px 8px 0px;
    background-image: url('img/head-img.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#nav {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: fantasy;
}

#nav a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: underline overline;
}

#dlogo {
    position: absolute;
    /* background-color: #feffe3; */
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#dtext {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#blogo {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#btext {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 40%;
}

#wrapper {

}

#content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#content h1, h2 {
    color: orange;
    font-family: serif;
}

#content a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content a:hover {
    color: red;
}

#footer {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #1d726d;
    margin-top: 40%;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dlogo">
                <img id="blogo" src="img/back-img2.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="dtext">
                <img id="btext" src="img/f-it2.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="nav">
                <a href="">Home</a>
                <a href="">About Us</a>
                <a href="">Solutions</a>
                <a href="">Success Stories</a>
                <a href="">Contracts</a>
                <a href="">Careers</a>
                <a href="">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you look closely you will see that the black nav bar / header will not stretch all the way from side to side.

**It seems like a 10px margin has been applied to the whole website.**

How do I get rid of the "margin" that I never applied, but does not happen to any other website.

I am using netbeans, chrome, and xampp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a reset stylesheet to reset the default rules that browsers add to webpages. [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and [YUI's](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) reset stylesheets are good for most webpages. Personally, I use Eric Meyer's for my webpages. Make sure to place the reset stylesheet before any other stylesheets.

Comment: As quick fix, set the margins of the body to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
html {
   padding:0px;
   margin:0px;
}
```

Or am I missing the point here? Not very many details were given, if you could elaborate? It helps. :D

Also, giving your div a negative `margin` value is what I do sometimes.